# Migrate 16-bit get disk free space to 32-bit

Tags: c++, dos, diskspace

I used this code in my 16-bit application to get free space on the C drive.
The result was:

```
127 sectors/cluster,  15747 clusters, 512 bytes/sector, 15747 total clusters.
```

But when tried to migrate my code to 32-bit, functions like intdos, int86x... do not work. I tried to use GetDiskFreeSpace, but I obtained this instead:

```
Bytes/Sector = 512 Sectors/Cluster = 8 dwFreeClusters  = 41af86 dwTotalClusters = 9c3dbd
```

Please help me to migrate this code to 32-bit and obtain the same result:

```
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdio.h>
union REGS inregs, outregs;
main()
{
    inregs.h.ah = 0x36;  /* get disk free space function number */
    inregs.h.dl = 3;       /* drive C: */
    intdos(&inregs, &outregs);
    printf("%d sectors/cluster, %d clusters,%d bytes/sector, %d total clers",
    outregs.x.ax, outregs.x.bx, outregs.x.cx,
    outregs.x.dx);
}
```

Comment: Are you serious? :D This question has made my day :D

Comment: why don't use system APIs?

Comment: What 32-bit compiler are you using? From the sounds of things you're trying to use a 32-bit Windows compiler as if it were a 32-bit MS-DOS compiler. You also need to show the 32-bit code that produces what you think is the incorrect result. Finally, it doesn't look like the value your 16-bit application prints is actually correct, as 127 sectors per cluster would be very unusual.

Comment: The code with intdos work with a TurboC compiler, It is a little part from a function, it works fine in dos/16b application. But we need to migrate this function in 32b, i used  free C++Builder 5 command line  tool development system, we need to result "Sector per cluster", 
"Bytes per sector", "Free cluster", "Total cluster"

Comment: The free Borland C++ 5.5 compiler only supports Windows, not MS-DOS. So presumably you're really targeting Windows, and mistakenly think the Windows command prompt is MS-DOS. `GetDiskFreeSpace` is indeed the function you want to use on Windows. Since you haven't shown the code that uses `GetDiskFreeSpace` it's not possible to say what, if anything, might be wrong with it. Since your example 16-bit output seems to be incorrect, there may in fact be nothing wrong with your 32-bit program's output.